# How to remove the first index of an array based on input value?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I apologize in advance if i'm not conveying things properly.

I'm trying to take an array, split the strings into characters, and remove the first index if it matches my input value, and continue linearly.

I'm a little lost on how I should be thinking about solving this problem.
So far I have gotten to here,

```
 showCurrentValue = (event) => {
  const value = event.target.value;
  document.getElementById("textV").innerText = value;

  let arrIndex = newArr[0].split('');
  for (let i = 0; i < arrIndex.length; i++) {
    if (value === arrIndex[0]) {
      console.log("Match");
      arrIndex.shift()
    } else {
      console.log("Err")
    }
  }
}
```

With or without the loop it still behaves the same, it DOES remove the first index, but fails to continue, and logs "Err" for all the rest of the characters in the string. It won't match the next character. In my head i'm thinking if I just target the 0 index, and the array will update as each character is removed(?).

Hope someone can shine some light on this, Thanks!!

Basically, i'm trying to build one of those Typing speed test applications.
So I have my array of randomized words rendered to the DOM with an input field below it.

If, the input value matches the first character, I want to manipulate it based on if true or false. Change it's color, remove it from the DOM, etc.
So, my issue currently is getting the 2nd character of my input to compare to the next current character index.

Maybe my whole approach is wrong(?)

Comment: Are you simply wanting to filter out all characters that match another character from an input? Like `const filtered = newArray[0].split('').filter(char => char !== value)`?

Comment: Sorry, could you clarify what you are trying to accomplish? I understand, that you are looping through every character, but why are you shifting? Do you want to transform `aaaVaaVa` into `aaaaaa`?

Comment: Could you give us an example input and expected output, that will help us to understand what your function is trying to accomplish.

Comment: Sorry, I edited post above to clarify a bit if that helps.

Comment: I'm guessing this function is an event handler for a keydown event. In that case, `event.target.value` is the key that you pressed for that one event. Maybe you can try doing a `console.log` on your `value` variable to visualise what your function is doing.

Comment: Ahh yes, I see now. It's not comparing the individual input values. It compares the whole input. So now I got to figure out how to control WHAT the input is using as a comparison. 

Instead of comparing "bl   " to ["l", "u", "e"]. Im assuming it's comparing BL to L. When i'm trying to compare the L to the L.

Answer (score 0):

The first time you hit a situation where your `value !== arrIndex[0]`, you keep viewing the same element (`arrIndex[0]`) and not iterating to the next element.

@wlh's comment is pretty close to the solution I think you're looking for:

```js
const filtered = arrIndex.filter(char => char !== value);
```

`filtered` will then have all the elements of `arrIndex` but remove any and all elements that matched `value`.

Answer (score 0):

This is just one possible solution. You continue moving thru `arrIndex` with out changing its length, checking each case, and adding the cases which don't match your value to a new array. Once you have finished moving thru the `arrIndex` then you assign `arrIndex` to the `updatedIndex`;

```
 showCurrentValue = (event) => {
  const value = event.target.value;

  let updatedIndex = [];
  const arrIndex = newArr[0].split('');
  for (let i = 0; i < arrIndex.length; i++) {
    if (value !== arrIndex[i]) {
      console.log("Err");
      updatedIndex.push(arrIndex[i]);
    } else {
      console.log("Match")
    }
  }
  arrIndex = updatedIndex.join(''); 
}
```

Another solution could be

```
 showCurrentValue = (event) => {
  const value = event.target.value;

  let arrIndex = newArr[0].split('').filter((char) => char !== value);

  return arrIndex;
}
```

`.filter` will return a new array - it will loop thru each `char` and return ones which don't match your `value`